# Isolation lemma

Tags: complexity-theory

Here is a link to the isolation lemma. Please refer to the statement and Spencer's proof at the given link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_lemma

In its statement, shouldn't there be a condition $N>=n$ since the probability is defined as $1-n/N$? Also, is it not required that the intersection of all sets in a given family of subsets is null? Otherwise, for $x$ that lies in every set of a given family, how can the threshold for $x$ be calculated as described in Spencer's proof?

Comment: Please include all necessary material in your question, rather than expecting people to cross-reference your question against another web page.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: it appears you may have created two usernames.  I encourage you to create an account, and merge the multiple accounts/usernames you created.  This will ensure that you retain access to your account, that you can edit the question, and that you can post comments under the question in response to feedback from others.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts, https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/why-register, and https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts.

Comment: ajax, from the edit you tried to post from an unregistered account, it looks like you've created multiple accounts. You can merge them all by clicking the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Note that $1-n/N$ is just a lower bound on the probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two questions. To answer your first question, if $N \leq n$ then $1-n/N \leq 0$, so the statement is vacuous (every probability is always non-negative). The isolation lemma is only interesting when $N > n$. Note that the claim isn't that the probability of isolation is *exactly* $1-n/N$, but rather that it is *at least* $1-n/N$.

Regarding your second question, if some $x$ is common to all sets, then you can just ignore it (the condition holds iff it holds for the system with $x$ removed from all sets). This means that the statement should actually hold with the larger probability $1-(n-1)/N$.

Comment: How does one justify the last line in the proof "As there is a unique minimum-weight subset iff no element is singular, the lemma follows."? I don't see the connection.

Comment: I understand what the problem is when N<=n. That is why the constraint on N and n should be stated explicitly in the hypothesis. I realized later that x can be dropped. But what if the sets are not pairwise disjoint? One could have a situation in which x∈A \intersect B and w(A)=w(B). No matter how w(x) changes w(A)=w(B). If w(A) is sufficiently low one may have multiple values of x for which there is no unique minimum weight set. But if the sets are pairwise disjoint  then the lemma could be true. There might be other conditions required. I don't know.

Comment: For a certain w, what if there are two subsets A and B with w(A)=w(B) and w(A) is the set with minimum weight regardless of what value x takes? For example, both A and B might be singletons each with weight 1. For this w, there is no hope of having a set with unique minimum weight.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Spencer's proof, and it doesn't require your extra hypotheses. Regarding your other question about "probability cannot be negative", you're right that probabilities cannot be negative, but they can be *at least* a negative number. For example, *every* probability is at least $-1$.

Comment: Yes. That is right. It is >=.